# Deploy on different context on embedded Jetty in GWT hosted mode

Tags: gwt, jetty, gwt2

While running my webapp using GWT hosted mode, I haven't found a way to deploy it outside root context of Jetty. I could only do that while using an independent app server and running hosted mode without Jetty.

Is there a way to run directly on embedded Jetty, but outside of root context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether you checked up on google groups for this. This works for me https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/a8OsRmMSaMg

Create file `jetty-web.xml` in yours `WEB-INF` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
"http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd"> 
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext"> 

        <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set> 

</Configure>
```

Solution for GWT >= 2.6

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC 
    "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/contextpath</Set>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Just a side note: This file should be created inside your application's WEB-INF folder, not on the server configuration files like I thought at first.

Comment: This gives me a `ClassNotFoundException : org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext` in gwt 2.6.0. Do you know of a solution that would work with 2.6.0 ?

Comment: This is related to changes in jetty support by GWT in 2.6 release. You would need to change your launch approach or modify web.xml. Please observe the stacktrace and attempt a google search on the related error information.